# How to set initial queue length (queue_count) in simmer R?

Tags: r, reinforcement-learning, simpy, event-simulation

I am trying to run a simmer environment multiple times with a changing initial queue.

How can a set an initial queue?
I tried `set_queue_count()` but this function does not exist.

As follows you can see the code:

```
library(simmer)

env = simmer()

traj = trajectory() %>%
  seize("res", 1) %>%
  timeout(1) %>%
  release("res", 1)



env %>%
  add_resource("res", 1) %>%
  add_generator("event", traj, function() rexp(1, 5)) %>%
  add_generator("starter", traj, at(rep(0, runif(1, 0, 5))) # The random number is only generatet once



n = 0

while(n < 10){
  reset(env)
  env %>%
    run(10)

  n = n + 1
}
```

I also tried to `add_dataframe()` with a random number of events arriving at time 0 but unfortunately the dataframe cannot be alterd during the episodes, hence the initial queue stays the same.

The whole environment is ultimately being used for a reinforcement learning application.

Comment: Note that your loop is not doing anything after the first execution. If you want to re-run the simulation, you need to reset the environment first. About the question, feeding random arrivals at t=0 is the way to do this. You don't need to use `add_dataframe` if this doesn't meet your purpose, you can use `add_generator` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implement your suggestions but the random number is only generated once at the beginning and not for every episode as I'd like. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Try something like `function() c(rep(0, sample(5, 1)), -1)`. The `-1` is to stop the generator after the first execution.